# After $http request AngularJS bootstrap modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a pop-up modal within my angular page. I found the code on [this site](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), and it is working fine. However, I also have a button for `http` request on the same angular page, and after the `http` request preforms, the angularjs modal no longer works.

I receive the following error in my conolse:

`GET http://localhost:8080/SampleApp/myModalContent.html 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: What is the `http` request for? Is it getting the myModalContent.html partial? The 404 is telling you exactly what the issue is. It can't find that html partial. Is your server up? If you type that entire url in a separate browser tab what is the response?

Comment: how do you expect us to help you with a bad path without more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I think myModalContent.html isn't exist in SampleApp folder. Be sure.

Comment: Hey there! did u get ur answer i am seriously stuck with this.